How many configurations are there such that If I delete N cells from a NxN grid, every row, column and main diagonal has an even number of elements?
I was taking a look at Nob Yoshigahara mathematical puzzles and there was one asking that if there were a 6x6 grid, would it be possible to remove 6 cells from it such that every row, column and main diagonal had an even number of elements afterwards. The answer is yes and I could figure out many solutions by hand. But I neither could find how many solutions there are nor generalize it for a NxN grid. Does anyone know how to attack this problem? If I'm not clear, for instance, for n=3, if I delete all the 3 the cells on a main diagonal, the new grid will satisfy the condition.

Can you show your work and demonstrate how you can do this for $N=6$? $\quad$ Note: I claim that it cannot be done (at least in terms of how I interpret the question).

I'm sorry maybe this was a little confusing because english is not my first language and this is my first time using this forum. For user2661923, I don't know what you mean by a and b being negative. But I'm sorry I think that's not what I was asking for. For Calvin, draw a 6x6 sudoku grid, and remove the following cells, considering the matrix notation, a_ij is the cell at row i column j: a_12, a_32, a_34, a_54, a_56, a_16. Notice that removing that cells, every row, column and main diagonal has an even number of cells. The number of solutions (grids that satisfy it) is what I look for.

Oh thank you , I realized what my mistake was.

I have deleted all of my previous comments.  For some reason, I misinterpreted the question into thinking that you wanted to remove exactly $~1~$ cell from each row and simultaneously $~1~$ cell from each column.  Instead, you are asking how to remove $~6~$ cells such that an even number of cells remains in each row, column, and main diagonal.  So, all of my previous comments, which I have now deleted, did not apply to the question that you were asking.

Clarification requested: Is there one main diagonal, or two main diagonals?

There are two main diagonals. I'm sorry if the question was hard to understand, I really struggle with english.
